# Does the Zookeeper have a process synchronization capabilities or is it only for controlling processes?

Tags: synchronization, redis, ipc, rabbitmq, apache-zookeeper

I mean does the zookeeper offer any common synchronization mechanisms IPC (e.g. shared region) or is it a question of application design and should be implemented with e.g. ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, Redis?

Answer (score 0):

"Zookeeper is a highly configurable, highly available coordination service."  from the Hadoop book as Hadoop is built with Zookeeper under the hood.  Comparing it with JMS messaging (MQs) --- in Zookeeper the nodes have to know about each other, they're ready to coordinate; queues could be compared to Znodes I guess... with Zookeeper there are two types: permanent which will persist after the node goes down and across the cluster and transient; which won't persist but are still seen across the zookeeper cluster. Comparisons are tough-- guess it would depend on how it needs to be used.  I might use MQ's for long-range messaging whereas Zookeeper would be more for the coordination (keeping of the zoo) than for long haul messaging.  One might think of coupling and how tightly or loosely things are coupled.

In a very simplistic use case, all nodes are running Zookeeper and are aware of each other; one node writes something to Zookeeper they all see it.  Zookeeper has watches which could be compared to eventing. so if a new znode appears or if data changes on a node then a program or service could be triggered to do something.

zkCli.sh (in the bin dir of zookeeper) launches an interface into zookeepr after that, one can do, 'ls,' and see what's been written in terms of, 'znodes.'  So for example: 'ls /Systems' might, depending on what its for, show a bunch of nodes such as system1, system2,system3. ...systemn.' These could be systems that are registered, i.e: they have a service that registers them running on them.  Doing a get /Systems/system1 gets its data which might be information on the system such as memory or what its working on.

There's more but hope that helps.